# problems with nested json_query

Tags: ansible, json-query

I have the following json structure.

```
    "results": [
        {
            "ltm_pools": [
                {
                    "members": [
                        {
                            "full_path": "/Common/10.49.128.185:8080",
                        },
                        {
                            "full_path": "/Common/10.49.128.186:8080",
                        }

                    "name": "Staging-1-stresslab",
                },
                {
                    "members": [
                        {
                            "full_path": "/Common/10.49.128.187:0",
                        },
                        {
                            "full_path": "/Common/10.49.128.188:0",
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Staging-2-lab",
                },
```

I get an error when trying to do something like this

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{item[0].host}} --- {{ item[1] }} ---  {{ item[2] }}"
    with_nested:
      - "{{F5_hosts}}"
      - "{{bigip_facts | json_query('[results[0].ltm_pools[*].name]') | flatten }}"
      - "{{bigip_facts | json_query('[results[0].ltm_pools[?name.contains(@,'Staging'].members[::2].full_path]') | flatten }}"
```

I am unable to get the third array working.

I want to print the even members full_path variable from all objects where name contains staging.

I hope someone can help me I've been struggling with this for days.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see/read/tried myself, you fell in this bug: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27299

This is the problem of "contains" JMESPath function as it is run by Ansible, to quote:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27299#issuecomment-331068246

> The problem is related to the fact that Ansible uses own types for strings: `AnsibleUnicode` and `AnsibleUnsafeText`.
>   And as long as jmespath library has very strict type-checking, it fails to accept this types as string literals.

There is also a suggested workaround, if you convert the variable to json and back, the strings in there have the correct type. Making long story short, this doesn't work:

```
"{{bigip_facts | json_query('results[0].ltm_pools[?name.contains(@,`Staging`)==`true`].members[::2].full_path') }}"
```

but this does:

```
"{{bigip_facts | to_json | from_json | json_query('results[0].ltm_pools[?name.contains(@,`Staging`)==`true`].members[::2].full_path') }}"
```

I've managed to run such a code:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        bigip_facts: 
          results: 
            - ltm_pools:
                - members: 
                    - full_path: "/Common/10.49.128.185:8080"
                    - full_path: "/Common/10.49.128.186:8080"
                  name: "Staging-1-stresslab"
                - members: 
                    - full_path: "/Common/10.49.128.187:0"
                    - full_path: "/Common/10.49.128.188:0"
                  name: "Staging-2-stresslab"

    - name: "Debug ltm-pools"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{bigip_facts | to_json | from_json | json_query('results[0].ltm_pools[?name.contains(@,`Staging`)==`true`].members[::2].full_path') }}"
```

And it works as you wanted:

```
PLAY [all] *****************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Debug ltm-pools] *****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'/Common/10.49.128.185:8080']) => {
    "msg": [
        "/Common/10.49.128.185:8080"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'/Common/10.49.128.187:0']) => {
    "msg": [
        "/Common/10.49.128.187:0"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```